# Is it worth playing this game of dice?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, puzzle

We pay $\$42$ so we can throw $3$ fair $6$ sided dice. We get back the product of the resulting dice values.

Is it worth playing this game?

What is the expected value of your winnings (or losings) after $10$ rounds of this game?

From how I understand it, the expected value after $10$ rounds should be $(3.5^3)*10$. Also each round is $3.5^3$ which is a little over 42, so it should be worth playing. Is this correct? How would you write it formally?

Comment: yeah, I realized after writting it, that I had it wrong, still not sure if its correct though

Comment: @Winther: Thanks, I did the arithmetic in my head, badly. Need more coffee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Z$ be the random variable corresponding to the product of the 3 (independent, fair) dice, when you roll them. Then $Z=U_1U_2U_3$, where the $U_i$ are iid random variables, uniform on $\{1,\dots,6\}$.
In *one* experiment,  when you play, the expected gain is
$$
\mathbb{E} Z-42 = \mathbb{E}[U_1U_2U_3] - 42 = \mathbb{E}[U_1]\mathbb{E}[U_2]\mathbb{E}[U_3] - 42 = \left(\mathbb{E}[U_1]\right)^3 - 42 = \left(\frac{7}{2}\right)^3 - 42
$$
where we used independence of the $U_i$. Repeating it 10 times multiplies this expected gain by 10; the expected gain is therefore $g = 10\cdot\left(\mathbb{E} Z-42\right)$ it is worth playing, thus, if
$
g \geq 0.
$